# Referencia Nula en Model

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc, pdf

Estoy teniendo este problema:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este problema surge cuando intento mostrar los valores de SQL en PDF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen, hay un link para ver los valores en PDF, al clickear allí sale el error ya mencionado.

Les comparto el código:

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string buscarTitulo)
        {
            PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter();
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = buscarTitulo;

            var datos = from s in db.SQLs
                        select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(buscarTitulo))
            {
                datos = datos.Where(s => s.Titulo.ToString().Contains(buscarTitulo.ToUpper()));
            }
            return View(datos.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Pdf()
        {
            var reporte = new ActionAsPdf("Index");
            return reporte;
        }

        public ActionResult Impresion(double? tit) {
            using (PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter()) {
                V_CuetaWeb v = db.SQLs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Titulo == tit);
                List<V_CuetaWeb> lista = new List<V_CuetaWeb>();
                lista.Add(v);
                var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf", v);
                return reporte;
            }
        }
```

**Index:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProvidusCuotas.V_CuetaWeb>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("buscar", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print()" />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                        <td>

                            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    </tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Impresion", new { id = item.Titulo })
                    </td>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**La vista del pdf: **

```
@model IEnumerable<ProvidusCuotas.V_CuetaWeb>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PDF";
}


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Domicilio">Domicilio: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domicilio)
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Valor Nominal: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValNom)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Barrio">Barrio: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Barrio)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Localidad">Localidad: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Localidad)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Telefono">Teléfono: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefono)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Celular">Celular: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Descripcion">D. Plan Actual: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescPlanActual)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Fecha">Fecha Sorteo: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaSorteo)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Zona: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acidzona)</th>
                        <th>Cobrador: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cobrador)</th>
                        <th>Código: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)</th>
                        <th>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Endoso)</th>
                        <th>Sorteo: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</th>
                        <th>Cuota: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</th>
                        <th>Vencimiento: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</th>
                        <th>Monto: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monto)</th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Clase PDFPRinter:**

```
public partial class PDFPrinter : DbContext
    {
        public PDFPrinter()
            : base("name=VisorPDF")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        //public virtual DbSet<V_CuetaWeb> V_CuetaWeb { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<V_CuetaWeb> SQLs { get; set; }
    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Que tipo te devuelve *datos* en el método Index?

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo tu pregunta @PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser que tu Model no esta recibiendo la data que tu preparastes. 
Puedes probar esta solucion.

```
public ActionResult Index(string buscarTitulo)
        {
            PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter();
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = buscarTitulo;

             //Contains(buscarTitulo) se convierte en LIKE '%hello%'. 
            // El operador LIKE  es case insensitive por defect,
            var datos = db.SQLs.Where(s => s.Titulo.ToString().Contains(buscarTitulo ?? s.Titulo.ToString())
                               .Select(d => d)
                               .ToList()

            return View(datos);
        }
```

Espero esto resuelva su situacion.

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, la implementaré y te contaré que tal me fue.